# WebView in Android Studio does not show sites properly (i.e. www.google.com is without logo, search bar and all the stuff on upper screen)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have a problem with showing simple google.com in my WebView.
Tried this on few emulators and 2 phones, all the same, something is wrong with my code.

**1. Issue**

- First screen shows normally google's asking user to accept their legal stuff (1st image).
- After accepting it moves to google's main page. But only lower part (Country, settings, adds, about etc.) is shown (2nd image). There is no Google logo, no search bar and buttons and no stuff from the upper display (like GMAIL, GRAPHICS, ACCOUNT and so on).
  [1ST SCREEN OF GOOGLE.COM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brvWT.png)
  [INCORRECTLY SHOWN GOOGLE PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzAUt.png)

**2. Code**

- I added permission in Manifest.
- Trying to solve the issue I stackoverflowed below two lines and added to Manifest, but to no avail:
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

**
3. My java code is below:**

(each of the settings I tried to comment out and then one by one uncomment, but still no result).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Could someone please check this is tell me what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid thing, should not have done this late into the night.

The problem was only with layout, rest of the page was out of screen.
Needed only to match the WebView to constraints.